# How to convert eclipse PyDev project into an executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, eclipse, pydev, pyinstaller

I have PyDev project with the below structure

**Project**

- src

  ```
     - module 1
     - module 2
     - module 3
           - Main.py
  ```

How to convert the entire application into exe. I have used python 3.6.4 , PyQt5, pdfminer.six etc.

I tried pyinstaller but exe is not running. It results in OSERROR

Comment: As a note, this isn't really related to PyDev (it has no such functionality) and you're in the proper path (the freezing of python applications are usually done through one of pyinstaller, cx_freeze, py2exe or py2app), but without the real error it's hard to diagnose anything.

Comment: @FabioZadrozny I solved this issue by adding the entire project folder path to the pyinstaller spec file. Thanks.